# Writing my first ROS program using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, ros

I am trying to write my very first ROS Porgram (Hello world) using Visual Studio 2022.

I am using my Windows 10 computer. I managed to install ROS (noetic) on my computer and create a terminal window for it on windows terminal.

I saw this tutorial and try to give it a shot, however I have doubts if I am on the right track.

https://github.com/Brabalawuka/RosOnWindows

I managed to create my catkin ws and direct it to src like so:

c:\catkin_ws\hello_world\src>

However I was not able to run devel\setup.bat .

This is what it look like in my documents:

[image]

Can you please help me. I don't think I am far away.

Kind regards

Comment: Why were you not able to run `devel/setup.bat`?

Comment: Dont know. Do you know the possible reason. Am I on the right track?

Comment: No one can tell you without more information. Saying you can’t run something could mean anything. You need to be specific about how it doesn’t run correctly.

Comment: OK, when I run it response as:  " The system cannot find the path specified. "      When I open the devel folder in src it only consists of a BUILT_BY File (.built_by) file called " .built_by ". When I open the file using notepad it displays this,  " catkin_make ". So what should I do here? Do I need to change the file directory to src->devel or change the name of the file to setup?  I hope this information that I have provided is clear, I am not able to show screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming hello_world is a package I think it must be kept inside of the src folder. See this [Catkin_Workspace](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/workspaces#Catkin_Workspaces) for more details on the recommended layout for workspace.

Try building the workspace again and I hope it helps.